# How to hide the SectionIndex when a row is swiped and the Delete button appears

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there a way to hide the SectionIndex bar of a UITableView only when the Delete button of a row is visible?

1. Swipe the row
2. Delete button appears and sectionIndex disappears
3. Swipe the row back or press the button
4. Delete button disappear, or row is removed, and sectionIndex appears back

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to override the following UITableViewDelegate methods. This worked nicely for me:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    headerHeight = 0.0f;
    NSInteger sectionCount = self.theTableView.numberOfSections;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, sectionCount);
    [self.theTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    headerHeight = 30.0f;
    NSInteger sectionCount = self.theTableView.numberOfSections;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, sectionCount);
    [self.theTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return headerHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Create custom cell with delegate for class is contained table view;

2)use

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

for send messages to delegate to change status;